# Rails get dump of rendered view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

How can i include render response of a view inside another , but dumped.

like i am currently using:

```
css: "<%= render :partial => "myurl/blah", :formats=> [:css], :layout => false %>",
```

( in a rendered js file, where i am creating a json object and including various other files too.. )

The response here is like this :

```
css: "#utilities {width: 800px;}
#utilities p,
#utilities ul {margin-bottom: 1em;}
#utilities_scroll {height:500px; padding:0 10px 0 10px; overflow:scroll;}
#utilities_scroll_inner {width: 733px;}
#utilities-search-form {margin-top: 20px;} .. ."
```

However i want dump of it like this :

```
css: "#utilities {width: 800px;}\n#utilities p,\n#utilities ul {margin-bottom:  .. "
```

**EDIT:**

In response to:

```
css : <%= eval("render :partial => 'myurl/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false").dump %>
```

It is dumping the html but slightly incorrect way,

See in rails console :

```
 a = "fdjasdlkfs 32$#%$#^$%^<>tv5$ ;'"  # => "fdjasdlkfs 32$#%$#^$%^<>tv5$ ;'" 
a.dump      #=> "\"fdjasdlkfs 32$#%$#^$%^<>tv5$ ;'\""
```

That would be correct way but , in html with the line i'm including , the response is as :
(if i have in myurl/blah.css  file as : `"fdjasdlkfs 32$#%$#^$%^<>tv5$ ;'"`

The result  is

```
css : &quot;\&quot;fdjasdlkfs 32$#%$#^$%^&lt;&gt;tv5$ ;'\&quot;\n&quot;
```

see the difference as `< > "` are transformed very differently in both cases..( i needed it as per first format"

Comment: have you tried String.dump(http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.dump)

Comment: but thats the syntax for ruby... how can i use it with rails views...?

Comment: Try this : css : <%= eval("render :partial => 'myurl/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false").dump %>

Comment: i have modified the question ,, please have a look at problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vik for efforts... But after long hours of search i ended up as :

```
css : <%= JSON.dump(render :partial => "abc/url", :formats=> [:css], :layout => false).html_safe %>
css: <%= eval("render :partial => 'blah/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false").dump.html_safe%>,
css: <%= eval("render :partial => 'blah/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false").to_json.html_safe%>,
```

as solution for the problem....
I have just started up on Ruby,rails and find strange there is no proper documentation regarding all these small things...hope this helps someone...

however in my case i ended up using for my solution as :
( a little diff from question )
in controller :

```
@cssrender = JSON.dump(render_to_string(:file => "blah/blah", :layout => false , :formats =>[:css]))
```

and in view just `css :<%=@cssrender.html_safe%>`

Answer (score 1):

Use eval . I never tried this before but it would work .

Try :

```
css : <%= eval("render :partial => 'myurl/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false") %>
```

Comment: `css : eval("render :partial => "url/abc", :formats=> [:css], :layout => false"),`  is printing this line as it is,  while also : ` track: eval("<%= render :partial => "url/xyz", :formats=> [:js], :layout => false %>"),` is printing `eval("my response from the rendered file as it is ")`

Comment: Oop's, can you please try edit one . I have just edited my response .

Comment: still not working.. now response is same as i was getting earlier (as in question)... btw where can i find some documentation regarding this...

Comment: not sure about such documentation , but you can use gsub to replace new lines with expected character (like : eval(...).gsub(/\n/,"\n")) . And can you let me know, why you want to response in such format .

Comment: the main file i m rendering is .js file, returning a object ( as per jsonp format)... say if i have : `content : " <div id="content-container"> .......... "` as one of its field, the it won't remain a valid object. but it would be valid object if it remain as : `content :"<div id=\"content-contatiner\"> ......."`, that's why i need the dump of the data as a value to mey key in the object i am sending out.